# How can I reshape one of these ndarrray to any one of these form? If possible please provide an example code

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to reshape any one of the ndarrays to another form. Here are the info of my two arrays ds1 and d respectively. I want to reshape either ds1 as d r viceversa. I've gone through the documentation but could not understand these type of reshaping conversions.

```
`np.info(ds1)`
```

Output:

```
 class:  ndarray
shape:  (698, 150, 150)
strides:  (22500, 150, 1)
itemsize:  1
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  False
data pointer: 0x9b7b9f9040
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: uint8

'np.info(d)'
```

Output:

```
class:  ndarray
shape:  (698, 2)
strides:  (2, 1)
itemsize:  1
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  False
data pointer: 0x9b7688fd90
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: uint8
```

I obtained d by reshaping another array of float64 type into uint8 as:

```
d = ds2.astype(np.uint8) #d to convert float64 to uint8
d
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

How do I convert either d as the same dimension array of d1 or vice-versa. If possible please help me with an example code.

Comment: `astype` doesn't change the `shape`.  `d` and `ds2` are both (698, 2) (right?).  `ds1` and `ds2` have different numbers of items, and can't be reshaped to match.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can do it with the `ds.reshape()` numpy method, but in your case, as stated by @hpaulj, it's impossible due to shape reasons.

```
ds1 = np.zeros((698, 2))
d = np.zeros((698, 150, 150))
d.reshape((698, 2))
```

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 15705000 into shape (698,2)`
Cheers.